# Java returning null and result

Tags: java

can someone take a look at this example and tell me why I get null10 as printed value instead of 10 only?

and is there and easier solution for this program without using global String variable "word"

```
public class UserInput {

    public static String word;

    public static class TextInput {
        public void add(char c) {
            word = word + c;
        }

        public static String getValue() {
            return word;
        }
    }

    public static class NumericInput extends TextInput {
        @Override
        public void add(char c) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                word = word + c;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextInput input = new NumericInput();
        input.add('1');
        input.add('a');
        input.add('0');
        System.out.println(input.getValue());

    }
}
```

EDIT: I need use inherits from TextInput

Comment: `word = word + c;` the first time you call `add`, `word` is `null` because you never initialized it, so `word` becomes `null` plus whatever you called `add` with.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your static `word` field an initial value, otherwise it will default to being `null`. And when Java concatenates String objects, it will treat a `null` reference as the literal string "null". So you're effectively always starting off with the String "null".

If you give your class field a starting value of `""` (empty string) then your code should do what you expect.

With regard to a better way of doing this, I would instead give the class a non-static field of type `StringBuilder` (and initialise it so that it's not `null`). Then your `add` method can simply `append(c)` the new characters to the `StringBuilder` field object, which will be more efficient than repeatedly using string concatenation (which is what you get with `word + c`).

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `input`, so it is `null`. You need to initialize `input` first in order to make concatenating work.

So, use this:

```
public static String word = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a static variable that is shared over all instances and children of the TextInput class, you should be using an instance variable.

You'll still have to initialize a non null value

That would look like

```
public static class TextInput {
    protected String word;

    public TextInput() {
        this.word = ""; 
    } 

    public void add(char c) {
        word = word + c;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

To better understand the problem, try your code with this

```
    TextInput input = new TextInput();
    input.add('a');
    System.out.println(input.getValue());
    TextInput input2 = new NumericInput();
    input2.add('1');
    input2.add('0');
    System.out.println(input2.getValue());
```

Additional, see @Bobulous comment about using StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You were not initializing the "word".

```
public class TextInput {
        public static String word=""; // a lil change here
        public static class TextInput {
            public void add(char c) {
                word += c;
            }
            public String getValue() {
                return word;
            }
        }
        public static class NumericInput extends TextInput {
            public void add(char c) {
                if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                    word += c;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            NumericInput input = new NumericInput();
           input.add('1');
           input.add('a');
           input.add('0');
           System.out.print(input.getValue());
        }
    }
```